# Diophantine Equation for Odd Numbers

Tags: diophantine-equations

Dealing with Diophantine equation I saw the following to be true and could arrive at a proof.  Has this been dealt with earlier any where ? $$x^p+y^q=z^r $$, where $$x, y, p, q, z, r$$ are all natural numbers. It can be shown that the above statement  is never true when $p $ and $q$ are even integers and $x$ and $y$ are odd integers and $r > 1$

Comment: Yes, a modulo four consideration gives this immediately. Except when $x=y=r=1$ and $z=2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are both odd, and $p$ and $q$ are both even, then $x^p+y^q\equiv2\pmod 4$. This forces $z$ to be even, but unless $r=1$ $z^r$ is then divisible by $4$. So $r=1$. But if we allow $r=1$, then the existence of solutions is not interesting. Sorry about exaggerating a bit in the first comment. It is just that I easily deduced $r=1$ and lost interest.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Yes by mistake I forgot to say that r > 1, thanks . It is interesting to note that when p= q=r a very small subset of FLT is proven with simple mathematics, which has been proven by the method of infinite descent.

Answer (score 0):

Without that requirement, there are solutions such as 
$$ \eqalign{0^2 + 1^3 &= 1^2\cr
1^2 + 2^3 &= 3^2\cr
3^2 + 3^3 &= 6^2\cr
6^2 + 4^3 &= 10^2\cr
10^2 + 5^3 &= 15^2\cr
15^2 + 6^3 &= 21^2\cr
21^2 + 7^3 &= 28^2\cr
28^2 + 8^3 &= 36^2\cr
36^2 + 9^3 &= 45^2\cr
45^2 + 10^3 &= 55^2\cr
\ldots&\cr
}$$

Comment: How do you generate these solutions from scratch?

Comment: @Robert Israel . You mean to say when the restriction of q being even is removed ?

Comment: @TobyMak $\left(\frac{y^2-y}2\right)^2 + y^3 = \left(\frac{y^2+y}2\right)^2$.